# Фраза «…встала и, покачивая бедрами…» — на месте ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

*«Она грациозно встала и, покачивая бедрами, вышла из комнаты».*
Правильно ли поставлена запятая? Может быть, запятая должна быть перед «и»? Или и до и после?
Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Answer (score 4):

Запятые выделяют деепричастный оборот. Первая запятая стоит на месте. Другие запятые не требуются, так как союз "и" соединяет однородные сказуемые "встала" и "вышла".

Answer (score 3):

Нет, всё правильно, обособляется именно сам деепричастный оборот. Перед И запятая не нужна, потому что это не ССП, подлежащее одно.